# Send file attachments in next.js via nodemailer

Tags: javascript, email, next.js, email-attachments, nodemailer

I am trying to send file attachments in my Next.js app using nodemailer.

My current setup consists of:
`ApplicationForm.tsx`

```
import { sendEmailForm } from '../../../../lib/api';

const initialState: IApplicationFormData = {
  files: [],
};

const ApplicationForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<IApplicationFormData>(initialState);
  
const handleFileUpload = (
  e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>
  ) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let fileList;
  if (e.type === 'change') {
    fileList = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
  } else {
  fileList = (e as React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>).dataTransfer.files;
  }
  const fileArray = Array.from(fileList || []);
  setFormData((current) => ({
    ...current,
    files: [...current.files, ...fileArray],
  }));
  };

const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
try {
  await sendEmailForm(formData, 'applicationMail');
  setFormData(initialState);
} catch (error: any) {
  console.log(error.message)
  });
}
};

return(
     <FileInput
        name={fileLabel}
        labelText={fileLabel}
        onChange={handleFileUpload}
        filePreview={formData.files}
        removeFile={removeFile}
        removeAllFiles={removeAllFiles}
        handleDragOver={handleDragOver}
      />
    )

export default ApplicationForm;
```

I save the uploaded files in the state as an array.

Following the fetch function in `lib/api.ts`

```
export const sendEmailForm = async (
data: any,
apiEndpoint: 'applicationMail' | 'contactMail' | 'callbackMail'
) => {
fetch(`/api/${apiEndpoint}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then((res) => {
  if (!res.ok)
    throw new Error(`Failed to send email, status code: ${res.status}`);
  return res.json();
});
};
```

Next.js API `applicationMail.ts`

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import {
applicationEmailTransporter,
applicationMailOptions,
} from '../../services/nodemailer';
import { generateEmailTemplate } from './../../lib/emailTemplate';

const applicationFormHandler = async (
req: NextApiRequest,
res: NextApiResponse
) => {
const data = req.body;
if (req.method === 'POST') {
if (!data.firstName || !data.lastName || !data.email || !data.message)
  return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Bad request' });
}

try {
  await applicationEmailTransporter.sendMail({
    ...applicationMailOptions,
    ...generateEmailTemplate(data),
    subject: 'New message',
  });
  if (data.email && data.email.length > 0) {
    try {
      await applicationEmailTransporter.sendMail({
        to: data.email,
        from: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPLICATION_EMAIL,
        subject: 'subject',
        text: `text`,
        html: `<p>html</p>`,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success' });
} catch (error: any) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
}
};

export default applicationFormHandler;
```

Lastly the `nodemailer.js` for the transporter

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';


const applicationEmail = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPLICATION_EMAIL;
const applicationEmailPassword =
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPLICATION_EMAIL_PASSWORD;

export const applicationEmailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
  user: applicationEmail,
  pass: applicationEmailPassword,
 },
});

export const applicationMailOptions = {
from: applicationEmail,
to: applicationEmail,
attachments: [
  {
    // Retrieve formData.files data from ApplicationForm.tsx 
    // filename: 'test.png',
    // path: './public/assets/test.png',
  },
 ],
};
```

My Question is if it would be possible to send attachments containing the file data from my `ApplicationForm.tsx` using just nodemailer or would i need a package like `multer`?

How would i refactor my current setup to properly send the uploaded files.

Thanks in advance!